# Удаление одного из двух одинаковых символов в строке

Tags: java, строки

Строка приходит такого вида. Это дата.

12.01.2018 12.33.15.01

где последний 01 это лишний элемент и мне его нужно substring (".01", ""), чтобы осталось 12.01.2018 12.33.15

но разумеется убирается и первое вхождение "01" - получается 121.2018 12.33.15
Подскажите пожалуйста как убрать последний символ в строке не затрагивая аналогичные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

newDate = date.substring(0, date.length() - 3)

Где 3 это последние 3 символа. А 0 это начало строки.